# How to Ignore Links in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement react router into my app but I am running into a issue where I have some "links" that display "modal" dialogs but react router is treating them as routes and sending me back to my "home" page

```
  <a href="#" onClick={() => this.props.Show(true) }><i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
```

router

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="app" name="app" component={App}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

That link is in a component in the "App" component.

Edit

I have this now

```
 return (
            <a href="#" id="add-new-storage-item-btn" className={addNewItemClasses} onClick={(event) => this.setAddStorageItemModal(event) }><i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"> Add New Item</i></a>
        );

  setAddStorageItemModal(event)
   {
       this.props.setAddStorageItemModal(true);
       event.stopPropagation();

   }
```

I tried putting event.stopPropagation as first line but does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want prevent an anchor tag from navigating, it is recommended that you add

`event.stopPropagation()`

to your `onClick` event handler.

Comment: Ah right, I tried to return false; but that did not seem to work so I did not even try this but it does work.

Comment: You can also assign `onClick()` to elements that aren't anchor tags

Comment: weird thought it was working but now it does not seem to be working.

Comment: seems like I have to use preventDefault to make it work.